# Do objects inherit?

Tags: java, inheritance

I have three classes `A`,`B` and `C`.
I have created object of class `A` in class `B` and I have inherit class `B` to class `C`.

Do the object of class `A` also inherit to class `C`?
Can I access member functions of class `A` through class `C`?

Comment: Try it and you'll know :)

Comment: "I have inherit class B to class C" means is B inheriting C or C is inheriting B?

Comment: That depends of the variable scope of the variable holding the A-object in B. If it's `private`, then no, if it's `public`/`protected`/`default`, then yes.

Comment: Do the object of class A also inherit to class C? No. Class A is just an inner class of B. The second question is too vague to answer.

Comment: Show us the code of your classes instead of describing it.

Answer (score 0):

You have used composition between A and B (B encloses an instance of A) and inheritance between B and C. So from C you can "get at" methods in B by using the `super` keyword. You may (depending on scope) thus also access members of A from within C, but you are not doing it directly by inheritance, as would be the case if C inherits from B and B inherits from A.

Comment: can I have a example??

Answer (score 0):

Here is a small example for your case use it,

```
class A
{
 String varOfA="Class A";
 private String locOfA="Local variable";
}
class B extends A
{
 int number=20;
}
class C extends B
{
 int total=number;
  void show()
 {
 System.out.println(super.varOfA);
 //System.out.println(super.locOfA); //This is a private variable variable, so it
 //won't be accessed from sub class
 System.out.println(total);
 }
}
public class MLInhert
{
 public static void main(String args[])
 {
 C obj=new C();
 obj.show();
 }
}
```

Please let me know if i made any mistake in this answer. Because i'm a beginner here.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the access specifiers of the variables in the class it is decided which class level variable can be accessed. See the table below:

[image: Source: Java oracle]

For more info refer : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html